# Magento get unique values from custom database table

Tags: php, database, magento, module

I created a custom module with a database table with the help of this [article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm).

I have a program which syncs stock from my physical store to online store. Every time I sync the stock, I add the sku,name, sync data and time, also the qty to the custom database table. There can be multiple entries for the same sku in the table as the same product can be synced multiple times.

Initially I was taking a report of the unique entries from the database table using this, where I was only getting the skus.

```
$collections = Mage::getResourceModel('module/namespace_collection')->distinct(true)->addFieldToSelect('sku')->load();
foreach( $collections as $collection){
    //add to csv
}
```

Now I want to get the sku and qty of the unique entries with the latest sync data and time for that particular sku. To get this I tried to use

```
$collections = Mage::getResourceModel('module/namespace_collection')->distinct(true)->addFieldToSelect('sku')->addFieldToSelect('qty')->addFieldToSelect('date')->load();
```

but I am getting all the entries in the custom table. Can some one help me out with this?

Answer (score 6):

Get unique records from collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('module/namespace_collection')
    ->getCollection()
    ->distinct(true)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->load();
```

The above collection if not return desire data, try this

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('module/namespace_collection')
   ->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```

But this will retrieve distinct values based on id. If you want to retrieve products using distinct sku values, you should group by "sku".

```
   $collection->getSelect()->group('sku');
```

If you want to debug the query executed :

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: This is the same as I tried. I am getting the unique values if I use one field to select, but I am not able to get the unique values when I have to select multiple fields.

Comment: use `echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();` & see the execute  query.

Comment: Thanks. I used this to find the executed query and found that I am getting the whole table data since i am trying to select date with the distinct filter. I found an SQL solution `SELECT t.sku,t.date,t.store_name
FROM my_database_table t
INNER JOIN(
 SELECT sku, max(date) as MaxDate
 FROM my_database_table
 GROUP BY sku
) tm on t.sku = tm.sku and t.date = tm.MaxDate;` but I am not able to convert this into a php code

Comment: No i just fond the sql query. How do i convert this into php code?

Comment: write direct query using [this](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

Comment: I was hoping to convert the sql into a getCollection statement. Thank you for your help. :)